# Return Future<void> from a sync function in Dart

Tags: dart, async-await

I have a function to override and I want it to do nothing. The base class function is abstract. I have two options for implementation:

```dart
// option 1
@override
Future<void> cancelReadStream() async {}

// option 2
@override
Future<void> cancelReadStream() {
  return Future.value();
}
```

Dart code metrics tells me to [avoid redundant async](https://dartcodemetrics.dev/docs/rules/common/avoid-redundant-async), so I thought it is best to return a `Future<void>`. Is `Future.value()` the best way to return a `Future<void>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd argue that the code metrics are wrong.

It's exactly the third item they list:

> - A value is returned and it will be impliclty wrapped in a future. `async` is shorter than `Future.value(...)`.

In this case the value is `null`, and it's returned implicitly, but it's still shorter than `Future<void>.value(null);`

The code

```dart
@override
Future<void> cancelReadStream() async {}
```

is perfectly reasonable and readable. It's an asynchronous function (returns a future), which does nothing before completing that future.

I'd consider reporting it to the DCM team, as a false positive.

Comment: I will have to check if later versions already fix it. I see I'm using 4.16.0

Answer (score 1):

I would go with option 1, it's just the most solid implementation.
Dart metrics can be a little invasive sometimes, I would just ignore it.
Once you actually write any async code the warning will disappear anyway.

Comment: option 1 would mean that I need to write `// ignore: avoid-redundant-async` above the method. So that's why I'm hesitating.

Comment: I also have a couple of function that perform something sync first. And although the method is marked to return a `Future<void>`, I will don't have anything to return, since it's just a simple synchronous method.

Comment: If it is a simple sync method, why can't you just delcare it as `void`? Because of the base class?

Comment: Correct, the base class requires `void` as return type. I can't just change that, since some implementations are async and require to return a `Future`.